# How to recreate the SVN 'format' file in a Repository?

Tags: svn, repository, format

We have been happily creating automated FAULTY backups of SVN repositories!!
It turns out that we were not backing up the file 'format' in each of the repositories.

Is there a way of recreating the file (and hence our repository and history)
I think (hope!) that this is the only file missing.

TIA 
Ivan Vernot

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a blank repository and copy the `format` file from there (assuming you have the same Subversion version as in your backup). The `format` file just has the repository version number in it.

Also, I would suggest you use a tool like hot-backup.py to do backups in the future :)

Comment: Thank codeka that worked but now I get a diffrent problem.
svnadmin dump <repo_name> returns with error
svnadmin: Can't open file '<repo_name>\db\revprops\0': Access is denied.
I have checked permisisons on the folders and all is fine but still, not go. (FWIW were running on Vista)